# Why does IE 11 automatically change the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript, string

I have got a problem with a javascript very strange.

On Chrome everythings works fine but in IE 11 the value of `name` changes for his self. I can't figured out what is going on here.

I've got the following javascript code:

```
name = field.name;

/* here some coditions and substr functionalities */

alert(name); // I see "postCode"

// This is false. field.value.length is 4
alert(name == "postCode" && field.value.length < 5); 

// here i see false as well | here i see "postCod", IE 11 take off last character.
alert((name == "postCode") "| name:" + name);
```

I am using some `substr` before of these checks.

I would like to know why in IE 11 the value of the variable `name` is automatically changed from one line to another. It becomes a shorter character.

Any idea what is going on here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: add `substr` code too

Comment: Is `name` in the global scope? Because, if so, it might be clashing with `window.name`.

Comment: You're working with a global variable, and that means that `name` is a property of the `window` object. Some of those have special meaning to the browser and it ignores attempts at assigning new values.

Comment: i'm gonna try to rename the variable `name` to see how it works.

Comment: Apart from the variable `name`, I would suggest using `===` instead of `==`, since the former will ensure that you are comparing the same types as well as values. The latter will attempt to do a type conversion first, and that is not always a recipe for success.

Comment: @PeterAbolins using `==` to compare what you are quite sure are strings shouldn't really lead to any abnormalities.

Comment: @vlaz Correct, but he is getting false, so either the type conversion is failing, or `name` really doesn't have the value he is expecting it to (in other words - never assume anything - even if you are **quite sure**).

Comment: @PeterAbolins do you also do `if (x > y)` immediately inside a nother `if (x > y)` condition *just in case* `x` and/or `y` changed values between two lines of code? There is "being careful" and "being unreasonable". What would using `===` solve in this case? If `name` was indeed some other random data type it would still return `false` whichever equality you use. Advocating "just use X" when there is literally no reason to is a cargo cult chant.

Comment: The last alert should only provide you with false, since the whole concatenated string gets compared to name. Else you would have to change it to something like this: alert((name == "postCode") + "| name:" + name);

Comment: @Peter Abolins: He/She gets false because he/she compares name with '"postCode" + "| name:" + name'. Which can never be true.

Comment: @Pointy @vlaz i changed my varible `name` to `thing` and it works perfectly. The problem was that i was calling the variable "name" and this was unstable. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Paplusc You should use `var name` inside of a function to avoid clashing with `window.name`.

Comment: @Paplusc: Your last alert will never work correctly, no matter how you call the variable. I somehow doubt that this was the real problem here.

Comment: @Lain yes yes, sorry, that was just an example in my real code it is not like that. :)

Comment: @Paplusc: Even with the global name variable the posted code works fine in IE11 and Chrome. At least in my consoles. So again, I doubt this being the real issue here.

Comment: @Paplusc: How could you even see "postCod" in the last alert if all you get is a booolean? :s

Comment: @Lain debugging :)

Comment: Well, atleast you fixed your substring I assume, the rest I call bs.

Comment: @Lain you can write the answer if you want :)

Comment: @Paplusc: Yes sure, an answer to a question which is incorrect, for a solution which can not be the issue, for an OP who is an edgelord in denial.

Comment: @vlaz You should always default to `===` because it creates a habit which prevents subtle bugs. This isnt the case of doing something pointless or redunant, it is the case of being strict and explicit so your intent is clear.

Comment: @Marie if @PeterAbolins had the intent to just recommend "best practice", then it failed since the `==` is actually the least of the problems of this code. There is `alert`, scoping and how to even do a proper check or comparison. While it might be a good habit, it does not pertain to the problem here and distracts from the real issues at hand. The way the "suggesion" was presented made it seem like using `==` *is* the problem. In fact, in the followup comment @PeterAbolins very clearly shows he thinks THAT is the problem with the code, it isn't just "you should be doing that in general".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you have `name` set as a global variable, this variable name is reserved by Javascript and used by the `window` object so it's creating a conflict.

You should avoid using the name of JavaScript built-in objects, properties, and methods.

A list of those can be found here:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Name is not reserved by javascript. That link just mentions that it is a common property name so you might want to avoid it. It does have a specific meaning in the global Window context so you shouldnt mess with it there if you dont need to. Beyond that you should use a better source than W3Schools, e.g. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)